# pymobbus write SINT16 bit

Tags: python, flask, plc, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

In my project I need to write negative intager in a PLC 1200 siemens. Now I'm using Pymodbus to write and read my register but I can't find a way to write negative integers because the console show me always this error:

"struct.error: argument out of range"

In this project I'm use Flask

this is my code:

```
def writeIntRegister(postName, address):
    post = request.form.get(postName)
    post = int(post)
    client.write_registers(address, post)
```

How I can decode the intager?

Comment: `post & 0xFFFF` would produce a 16-bit integer that would at least avoid this error, I can't guarantee it's in the format your PLC wants.

Comment: Ok thanks it's works but I also need to visualize it in the right format not in PLC but in a web page, do you have any hint?